# Can I boot a CD-ROM on a QEMU guest with a hard drive?

Tags: virtualization, boot, qemu, guest, optical-media

If I insert a CD-ROM into my server's physical CD-ROM drive, can I boot that CD-ROM in a QEMU guest to work on that guest's hard drive? I need to use a Windows 7 repair disk.

This is a continuation of my [previous](https://serverfault.com/questions/495980/how-do-i-create-an-iso-image-of-a-partition-on-an-external-hard-drive) [two](https://serverfault.com/questions/475618/how-do-i-transfer-a-windows-xp-vista-7-partition-into-xen) questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've attached /dev/sr0 to KVM/QEMU virtual machines through virt-manager and they've worked fine, I normally just mount the ISO from a datastore we have though.

This Server Fault post should help you :-)

[How to connect a cdrom device to a kvm/qemu domain (using command-line tools)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/373372/how-to-connect-a-cdrom-device-to-a-kvm-qemu-domain-using-command-line-tools)